# PHP / mySQL - Query to Retrieve Only Unique Meta Values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I need help in rewriting the query below to accept a second and a second + third qualification.

Example meta keys and values:

```
Trees
meta_key = trees
meta_value = pine, oak, sequoia

States
meta_key = states
meta_value = california, washington, florida

Countries
meta_key = countries
meta_value = usa, uk, ireland
```

I attempted to add these AND statements but I was not able to cause it to work properly.

Second qualification:

```
AND (pm.meta_key = 'states' AND pm.meta_value = 'california')
```

Second and third qualification:

```
AND (pm.meta_key = 'states' AND pm.meta_value = 'california')
AND (pm.meta_key = 'countires' AND pm.meta_value = 'usa')
```

Function with query I need help in rewritting:

```
function get_unique_post_meta_values( $key = 'trees', $type = 'post', $status = 'publish' ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;
    $res = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
AND p.post_status = '%s'
AND p.post_type = '%s'
", $key, $status, $type ) );
    return $res;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!  Please let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: your second/third qualifications were in the same query? That's not possible. you cannot require a single field (e.g. pm.meta_key) to have TWO different values AT THE SAME TIME. you can check for multiple SETS of values, e.g. `(a and B) OR (c and d)`

Comment: Thanks Marc for you feedback.  My knowledge is limited, so ever comment helps me to learn more.  Is it not possible in general or under the construct of the query within the function?  The query works fine for retrieve unique values for just "trees" but I need to further qualify and limit the retrieved values.  I thought this function might have been my solution.

Comment: It could work if meta_value were an array of 3. You might have an array of meta objects which include a meta_key and the meta_value array. I don't remember if PHP supports it the same way JavaScript and JSON do, though.

Answer (score -1):

If the function sets `$key=trees`, what is the point of an empty check? Additionally, I think you are missing the curly brackets. You are selecting 'pm.meta_value', which is why are you doing a LEFT JOIN, I think? Maybe seeing your DB structure would help me understand that, but an INNER JOIN is what you want.

```
if( empty( $key ) ){
 return;
} else {
    $res = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
SELECT DISTINCT pm.meta_value FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} as p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s'
AND p.post_status = '%s'
AND p.post_type = '%s'
    ", $key, $status, $type ) );
    return $res;
}
```

Try this. If it doesn't work then update this question with more details and I will help guide you further.